# File sharing between Android phone and a PC

Tags: android

I am new to the Android SDK. Is there a way to share files from my Android app, so that it can be accessed by another computer using WiFi? Is there support for something like SMB? 
(Android version on phone is 1.6)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an android SMB library available here:
http://code.google.com/p/sambaexplorer/

There are also some existing android SMB products out there like Pander-sync:
http://www.pader-sync.com/mobile-smb-client.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to look into the [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library.  SMB (or CIFS) could be made possible this way.  Although, I would suggest you look into some other mechanism for talking between your Android device and another computer.  Simple file browsing is one thing, but actual communication back and forth is a little more complicated.  You might want a daemon or systray app on the computer side.

Additionally, there could be some concerns related to security with SMB/CIFS.  You might have issues with the permissions on the computer, complexity of the configuration for the end-user on the Android side, or both.  Just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a solution for *sharing* files, but I used [AndFTP](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/index.html) to copy my ogg music files from my ubuntu box to the sdcard.

If by sharing, you just mean "use over the network" you can always put them on a webserver and put the url into android the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution for your phone, there is at least one samba client in the market.  I'm using SambaExplorer and it works quite well.  My HTC hero also comes with software from HTC that allows me to hook up my windows machine to my phone so I can move files  back and forth.

From an api perspective, you have access to essentially the same api's you would have in standard Java plus some additional things.  See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/index.html) for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/), you can then share files and web pages (even dynamic servlets!) using HTTP, and browse them from the computer using a normal web browser.

You can still browse them from the device itself, of course. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Astro File Manager with the SMB extensions, works for me!

Its easy to setup!

Answer (score 0):

[Samba filesharing app on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8239139&postcount=128) lets you share Android's 'external' storage device as a Windows/SMB shared folder over wifi, but currently minimum supported Android version is 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileLinx Professional from the Android market.

- Total access to PC's "`C`" drive.
- Works over Wi-Fi, 3G/4G...connect from anywhere.
- No "Cloud."
- Supports remote printing of most file types to your PC-connected
  printer.
- PC-side application is Java.
- Supports UPnP for easy port-forwarding.
- Saves settings for up to 10 PC's.

PC-side application is a free download.